# Django how to hide form based on value of another one

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-models, django-forms

I have a question for you. I'm trying to customize my crispy form based on my needs. 
But I have a problem that I wanna overcome.
Imagine that we have 3 forms

```
<div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" >
                          {{form.tipologia|as_crispy_field}}
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" >
                          {{form.descrizione|as_crispy_field}}
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" >
                          {{form.prezzo|as_crispy_field}}
                      </div>
</div>
```

And that I wanna hide the `form.prezzo` if descrizione is equal to `"Hello World"`. How could I get that?

**EDIT**

It's import that all update dinamically the field display. I have tried with the if statement directly on the template, but don't get the dinamical property. I think that the only solution is to implement a jquery script. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use condition in your template:

EDIT: for dynamic filtering, you can pass the value from your view that needs to be checked.

```py
context = {'form': your_form, 'value': 'Hello World'}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" >
        {{form.tipologia|as_crispy_field}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" >
        {{form.descrizione|as_crispy_field}}
    </div>
    {% if not form.descrizione == value %}
    <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" >
        {{form.prezzo|as_crispy_field}}
    {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry But your solutions is not dinamic. If I put another value don't update properly